# Flutter SharedPreference update when child route popped

Tags: routes, dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am kinda new with flutter and I start working around with SharedPreference. Everything works like charm, but when I make a change on a child route the parent route not updating.

I use the MaterialApp route parameter:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter app',
        home: Counter(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/settings': (BuildContext context) => new Settings(),
        });
  }
}
```

I have the parent route with initState which is working when start the app but when I open a new page and then make a change in the SharedPreference and after I go back to the main route the SharedPreference not changing because initState not running when you pop a route form the stack.

```
void initState() {
        SharedPreference().getLightsOn().then(updateLight);
        super.initState();
    }
    void updateLight(bool lt) {
        setState(() {
            _lights = lt;
        });
    }
```

My workaround was get to put it in the build widget to get the value, but I think it's not good method because it is looping over and over again.

```
Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
  SharedPreference().getLightsOn().then(updateLight);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push a new Page/`Widget`, you could use `await` keyword to wait after you pop the page. Like this :

```
      callNextPage() async {
        await Navigator.of(context).push(....);
        _readPreferences();
      }

      _readPreferences() {
        SharedPreference().getLightsOn().then(updateLight);
      }

      @override
        void initState() {
          _readPreferences();
          super.initState();
        }
```

Comment: Simple and awesome! Thank you!